# set the alternative row color for the first column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a table with some data. The first column of the table is set sticky. Now what I want is alternative color of each row in this first column only.

This is the table I am currently working on.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="4"></th>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">%Penetration</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let tableHeader of this.tableHeaders">
                    {{ tableHeader }}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
```

```
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: sticky;
    left: -1px;

}

td:first-child {
    background-color: white;
}
```

I have tried

```
td:first-child > td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: [:nth-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) have a look at this you can change the alternative row color by  using child concept

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453861/alternate-rows-in-one-column-only-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tr:nth-child(even) > td:first-child {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

here's the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRLVoY

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(1) {
            background: red;
        }
```

The output is

[image: alternative row color for the first column]